# Any way of solving this system of nonlinear equations with non integer powers?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, system, nonlinear

I have a system of four nonlinear equations. Some of the exponents are fractions. I was wondering if this is what is causing `NSolve` to run for hours without giving any results.

I first create a list of parameters that I eventually want to play around with to see how results change. This parameter list is "dat". I then specify the equations as follows:

```
dat = {alpha -> 1/3, beta -> 1/3, sigma -> 1/3, gam -> 0.5, 
  psy -> 0.5, delta -> 0.5, vu -> 0.5, a -> 1, A -> 1/3, B -> 1/3, 
  C -> 1/3, Ls -> 10, T -> 10, mc -> 1.5}

{p2 - w^psy pw^gam ((psy/gam)^gam + (gam/psy)^psy) == 0, 
  Ls - (beta/w)^(alpha + sigma) (pw/(alpha (1 + a C r T)))^
      alpha (r/sigma)^sigma (w Ls delta + r T A) - (pw psy/w gam)^
      gam ((w Ls vu + r T B)/p2) == 0, 
  T - (sigma/r)^(alpha + beta) (w/beta)^
      beta (pw/(alpha (1 + a C r T)))^alpha (w Ls delta + r T A) == 0, 
  pw - (((((1 + a C r T) alpha)/pw)^(beta + sigma) (w/beta)^
           beta (r/sigma)^
           sigma (w Ls delta + r T A) +  ((w gam)/(psy pw))^
           psy ((w Ls vu + r T B)/p2)) mc (1 + 
         a C r T))/((((1 + a C r T) alpha)/pw)^(beta + sigma) (w/
           beta)^beta (r/sigma)^
         sigma (w Ls delta + r T A)  + ((w gam)/(psy pw))^
         psy ((w Ls vu + r T B)/p2) (1 + a C r T)) == 0} /. dat
```

And then proceed with `NSolve`:

```
NSolve[%, {w, r, p2, pw}, Reals]
```

But Nothing happens. I tried using `Rationalize` but it does not seem to help. I am new to Mathematica so I hope that I am doing something wrong and that I missed something and can solve the system. Any suggestions?

Finally, how can I loop and redo this calculation with different parameters in the "dat" list?

Comment: (1) It seems that the complexity is beyond what `NSolve` can handle, at least in reasonable time. I converted decimals to rationals and set `exprs` equal to that system. From there, to see how complicated the underlying polynomial system is, you might do ``new = Internal`MakePolynomial[exprs]``.

Comment: (2) You might try for isolated solutions using `FindRoot` (instead of `NSolve`) with some set of starting values. Varying that set could lead to different solutions.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on Internal MakePolynomial? I have never seen this command before?

Comment: (You can't. Note the "Internal".) What it shows, though, is the construction of polynomials in some new set of variables, such that everything is explicitly polynomial in those variables. They are also shown in the second element of the `List` result.